# OAuth2RestTemplate Bearer Token Type

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm using Spring Security OAuth2 with OAuth2RestTemplate to implement a client for an OAuth 2.0 secured REST API. The flow goes through the steps to obtain the access token successfully:

```
response.statusCode = 200
response.body = {"access_token":"9b90f8a84b939b8437a4fbaa8fff0052839cf6f5","expires_in":3600,"token_type":"bearer","scope":" read write","refresh_token":"e164f317a1708c3664025e9e56ce605cfe710474”}
```

However, when the code tries to use OAuth2RestTemplate to access the protected resource, the response is unsuccessful:

```
GET request for "https://redacted.com/api/v1/clients" resulted in 400 (Bad Request)
```

This is because DefaultOAuth2RequestAuthenticator uses the token_type value ("bearer") returned with the access_token to form the Authentication header for the request to the protected resource:

```
request.getHeaders().set("Authorization", String.format("%s %s", tokenType, accessToken.getValue()));
```

This results in the credentials field in the request Authorization header being prefixed with the string "bearer":

```
Request Header: "Authorization" "bearer a8f18cb3173c4cbbea44f4495dd5e5662156c391"
```

However, according to the OAuth 2.0 Bearer Token Usage spec section 2.1 Authorization Request Header field, the format of the credentials field is:

> credentials = "Bearer" 1*SP b64token

Note that in the spec, "Bearer" is upper-case. This means that the request header should be:

```
Request Header: "Authorization" "Bearer a8f18cb3173c4cbbea44f4495dd5e5662156c391"
```

Apparently, the provider we're sending the request to implements the spec narrowly because the capitalization issue ("bearer" vs. "Bearer") is what's causing the request to the protected resource to fail. When I change DefaultOAuth2RequestAuthenticator to coerce the prefix to title case, the request succeeds:

```
if ("bearer".equals(tokenType)) {
    tokenType = "Bearer";
}

Header key = Authorization values = Bearer 8efd4381f3470660291e700e4927012f288ad66c,
Sending GET request to https://redacted.com/api/v1/clients
Received "200 OK" response for GET request to https://redacted.com/api/v1/clients: [[{"id":"999999999","client_user_id":"a1b2c3d4e5f6"...
```

I don't really want to have my own fork of Spring Security OAuth2 to fix this issue. How is this working for anyone? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem by these codes

```
    @Bean
public OAuth2RestOperations restTemplate(){

    AccessTokenRequest accessTokenRequest = new DefaultAccessTokenRequest();
    OAuth2ClientContext oAuth2ClientContext = new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext(accessTokenRequest);
    OAuth2RestTemplate oAuth2RestTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate( resource(),oAuth2ClientContext );
    oAuth2RestTemplate.setAuthenticator(new DefaultOAuth2RequestAuthenticator(){
        @Override
        public void authenticate(OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails resource, OAuth2ClientContext clientContext, ClientHttpRequest request) {
            clientContext.setAccessToken(new DefaultOAuth2AccessToken(clientContext.getAccessToken()){
                @Override
                public String getTokenType() {
                    if ("bearer".equals(super.getTokenType())) {
                        return "Bearer";
                    }
                    return super.getTokenType();
                }
            });
            OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = clientContext.getAccessToken();
            super.authenticate(resource, clientContext, request);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, it actually isn't working for a lot of people. There is an open issue in the spring-security-oauth issues list to address this (current milestone is 2.2.1):

[Use OAuth2 token_type equal "Bearer" by default everywhere #457](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/457)

The title may be a little misleading, but the comments outline this very issue and suggest work-arounds, which are all variants of overriding one of the OAuth2 token-handling classes to do what my fix to DefaultOAuth2RequestAuthenticator does.